# getElementById from button to dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass a parameter of my button values to dropdown list. The source code below is working but only for one button "Base 1", then if I press the other button the value in dropdown list will not change and still shows "Base 1"!

```
<div class="uk-margin">
     <div data-uk-button-radio="">
        <button id="sunny" class="uk-button" onclick="passValues()" value="1">Base 1</button>
        <button id="sunny" class="uk-button" onclick="passValues()" value="2">Base 2</button>  
     </div>
```

and for my dropdown

```
   document.getElementById('Floor').value = document.getElementById('sunny').value;
```

Comment: `ids` must be unique.

Comment: pass the clicked element reference to the function `onclick="passValues(this)"` then `function passValues(el){document.getElementById('Floor').value =el.value}`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks. worked perfectly!

Comment: @ArunPJohny: can you post your solution below in answer section so that OP can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">    
function passValues(el)
   {document.getElementById('Floor').value =el.value}
</script>
```

and for button:

```
onclick="passValues(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two elements cannot have the same ID. Give same class names. 
Then you can get correct value from **this.value** from the button click event.

```
<button class="sunny" class="uk-button"  value="1">Base 1</button>
<button class="sunny" class="uk-button" value="2">Base 2</button>


var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("sunny");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    alert(this.value);
});
};
```